# Convert string into MongoDB BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a long string in JSON format, and I want to convert it into a BSONDocument for insertion into a MongoDB database.  How do I do the conversion?  I'm using the official C# driver.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The answer is:

```
string json = "{ 'foo' : 'bar' }";
MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document
    = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
```

Answer (score 59):

```
string json = "{ 'foo' : 'bar' }";  
BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
```

Comment: Cool.. only one error-- 'BsonDocument' does not contain a definition for 'parse -- any idea why?

Comment: @VikashPandey: BsonDocument.Parse is included in the new .net driver for Mongo

Answer (score 5):

Using Version 2.1 of MongoDB's .NET library

```
string json = "{'foo' : 'bar' }";
var document = new BsonDocument();
document.Add(BsonDocument.Parse(json));
```

Comment: document.Add is obsolete now. Use document.addRange insted.