# problem with conversion of JSOn string to Mongo document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to convert a JSOn string into a Mongo document and there is not much help availabel online.

the only helpful thing that I found was:

1:
2:

MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument doc4=MongoDB.Bson.Serialization
 .BsonSerializer.Deserialize(genericjson);

Toggle HighlightingOpen in New WindowSelect All

as described  in the post @

[Convert string into MongoDB BsonDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624934/convert-string-into-mongodb-bsondocument)

It creates the document in the databse but it's not the simulation of what it is here in C#. When I click on the nodes they don't show me the data inside. this is what Mongo does when the conversion has corrupted the file.

is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [BsonDocument.Parse()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/b7ca6c27-2709-d294-8f83-d223c8cd947b.htm) method, e.g.

```
var bsonDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: Well. when I try to wite this code, it says that "Parse is not supported by BsonDocument"

Comment: BsonDocument.Parse() was added in v1.1 of the C# driver, you might need to update the driver.