# BsonDocument.Parse() problems converting String to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string into a BsonDocument with Parse() method, but I keep getting the error "Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'String'.". My string is in the following format: `string str = {'name': 'John', 'surname':'McLure'}` and I call the method this way `BsonDocument document = BsonDoucment.Parse(str)`.
I saw [Convert string into MongoDB BsonDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624934/convert-string-into-mongodb-bsondocument) and it says to use Parse method to convert a string into a BsonDocument, but it isn't working!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sample isn't valid C#, so it's hard to know exactly what *is* in your document. Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: You have `{ ]` ...

Comment: corrected, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Oh God, I solved this: the problem was with the format of the JSon string, I had

`string json_string = {'name': 'John', 'surname':'McLure'}`

, but BsonDocument.Parse() doesn't want fields in quotes, just the field name, so I changed it to

`string json_string = {name: 'John', surname:'McLure'}`.

Comment: But C# does want its whole strings inside `""`

Comment: IM working with an object serialized to JSON, and in C Charp it has a ton of quotes and backslashes  ```"\"{\\\"Zots\\\": \\\"zots are a unit of measure\\\", \\\"Krambles\\\": 12}\""``` -- surely there is a better way to parse from this thing?