# Litedb : Convert string to BsonDocument and vice-versa

Tags: c#, json, bson, litedb, bsondocument

When i convert bson to string using the following :

```
var stringDoc = LiteDB.JsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonDocument);
```

i'm getting the following :

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"62f3c9299c37811224131269"},"Name":"John Doe","Phone":"0778636316"}
```

When i try to convert back to bsonDocument using the following instruction :

```
BsonDocument bsonDocument = BsonMapper.Global.ToDocument(stringDoc);
```

I'm getting null in the bsonDocument variable.

Comment: Can the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210669/convert-string-into-litedb-bsondocument be helpful for you?